# config netty framework for tcp in spring boot web application

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, spring-security, spring-data-jpa, netty

I intend to create a webApplication which privides tcp socket for some modules for sending and recieving data over tcp connection.This application has a webApplication part which takes benefit from Tomcat and data JPA and Spring security Like many other web applications and On the other hand I used netty framework for providing tcp connection over this webapp. My main problem is everything work properly in an embeded tomcat but when i want to ndeploy that into a seprate tomcat context tcp connection wont get starter and i have got totally stuck;

my dependecies

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-configuration-processor -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.26</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-binding</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

my netty configuration and start point is like this

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableConfigurationProperties(NettyProperties.class)
public class NettyConfiguration {

    private final NettyProperties nettyProperties;

    @Bean(name = "serverBootstrap")
    public ServerBootstrap bootstrap(SimpleChatChannelInitializer simpleChatChannelInitializer) {
        ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
        b.group(bossGroup(), workerGroup())
                .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
                .handler(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.DEBUG))
                .childHandler(simpleChatChannelInitializer);
        b.option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, nettyProperties.getBacklog());
        return b;
    }

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdownGracefully")
    public NioEventLoopGroup bossGroup() {
        return new NioEventLoopGroup(nettyProperties.getBossCount());
    }

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdownGracefully")
    public NioEventLoopGroup workerGroup() {
        return new NioEventLoopGroup(nettyProperties.getWorkerCount());
    }

    @Bean
    public InetSocketAddress tcpSocketAddress() {
        return new InetSocketAddress(nettyProperties.getTcpPort());
    }

    @Bean
    public ChannelRepository channelRepository() {
        return new ChannelRepository();
    }
}


@Getter
@Setter
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "netty")
public class NettyProperties {
    @NotNull
    @Size(min=1000, max=65535)
    private int tcpPort;

    @NotNull
    @Min(1)
    private int bossCount;

    @NotNull
    @Min(2)
    private int workerCount;

    @NotNull
    private boolean keepAlive;

    @NotNull
    private int backlog;

    public int getTcpPort() {
        return tcpPort;
    }

    public void setTcpPort(int tcpPort) {
        this.tcpPort = tcpPort;
    }

    public int getBossCount() {
        return bossCount;
    }

    public void setBossCount(int bossCount) {
        this.bossCount = bossCount;
    }

    public int getWorkerCount() {
        return workerCount;
    }

    public void setWorkerCount(int workerCount) {
        this.workerCount = workerCount;
    }

    public boolean isKeepAlive() {
        return keepAlive;
    }

    public void setKeepAlive(boolean keepAlive) {
        this.keepAlive = keepAlive;
    }

    public int getBacklog() {
        return backlog;
    }

    public void setBacklog(int backlog) {
        this.backlog = backlog;
    }

}

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = 
        SpringApplication.run(JpaSecurityApplication.class, args);
        context.getBean(TCPServer.class).start();

    }
```

my security config is like this

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    AuthenticationSuccessfulHandlerImp authenticationSuccessfulHandlerImp;

    private final JpaUserDetailsService myUserDetailsService;

    public SecurityConfig(JpaUserDetailsService myUserDetailsService) {
        this.myUserDetailsService = myUserDetailsService;
    }

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests(auth -> auth
                        .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                        .antMatchers("/get/users").permitAll()
                        .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                        .antMatchers("/assets/**").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().permitAll())
                .formLogin().loginPage("/login").successHandler(authenticationSuccessfulHandlerImp).and()
                .userDetailsService(myUserDetailsService)
                .headers(headers -> headers.frameOptions().sameOrigin())
                .httpBasic(withDefaults())
                .build();

    }

    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}
```

also i excluded security config but nothing was changed

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {SecurityAutoConfiguration.class})
public class JpaSecurityApplication  extends SpringBootServletInitializer  {

   @Autowired
   UserRepository userRepository;


   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

       ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(JpaSecurityApplication.class, args);
       context.getBean(TCPServer.class).start();

   }

   @Override
   protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {

       return builder.sources(JpaSecurityApplication.class);

   }
```

I cant understand what happens and what causes this problem that prevents netty from start on a seprated tomcat. Its noteable that tomcat server does not generate any special error drunic compile process.It only loads the webapplication without netty being started.

below you can see the logs of embeded tomcat after starting the application

```
2023-03-27 16:01:23.610  INFO 10764 --- [           main] d.d.jpasecurity.JpaSecurityApplication   : Starting JpaSecurityApplication using Java 19.0.1 on sajadmovahedi with PID 10764 (C:\Users\s.movahedi\IdeaProjects\com\jpa-security\target\classes started by s.movahedi in C:\Users\s.movahedi\IdeaProjects\com\jpa-security)
2023-03-27 16:01:23.617  INFO 10764 --- [           main] d.d.jpasecurity.JpaSecurityApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-03-27 16:01:25.029  INFO 10764 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-03-27 16:01:25.199  INFO 10764 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 148 ms. Found 5 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-03-27 16:01:26.385  INFO 10764 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2023-03-27 16:01:26.397  INFO 10764 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-03-27 16:01:26.398  INFO 10764 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.65]
2023-03-27 16:01:27.014  INFO 10764 --- [           main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner     : At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
2023-03-27 16:01:27.030  INFO 10764 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-03-27 16:01:27.030  INFO 10764 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3315 ms
2023-03-27 16:01:27.273  INFO 10764 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2023-03-27 16:01:27.374  INFO 10764 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.11.Final
2023-03-27 16:01:27.696  INFO 10764 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2023-03-27 16:01:27.859  INFO 10764 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-03-27 16:01:28.004  INFO 10764 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2023-03-27 16:01:28.033  INFO 10764 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDBDialect
2023-03-27 16:01:29.090  INFO 10764 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2023-03-27 16:01:29.105  INFO 10764 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-03-27 16:01:30.367  INFO 10764 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure any request with [org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@37fd496a, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@6c4e486e, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@1755aee6, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@6f926d01, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@426940f9, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@77acc95a, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@5d10df04, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@10e4ce98, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@10466c55, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@27ac3b6d, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@1e3a2177, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@786cc1df, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@6bcfb561]
2023-03-27 16:01:30.442  WARN 10764 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2023-03-27 16:01:31.077  INFO 10764 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2023-03-27 16:01:31.090  INFO 10764 --- [           main] d.d.jpasecurity.JpaSecurityApplication   : Started JpaSecurityApplication in 8.186 seconds (JVM running for 10.588)
2023-03-27 16:01:31.093  INFO 10764 --- [           main] dev.danvega.jpasecurity.Netty.TCPServer  : Server is started : port 1234
```

and here seprated tomcat logs are seen able

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.7.4)

2023-03-27 16:04:50.384  INFO 8400 --- [nio-8085-exec-3] d.d.jpasecurity.ServletInitializer       : Starting ServletInitializer v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT using Java 19.0.1 on sajadmovahedi with PID 8400 (C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-tomcat-8.5.87\webapps\jpa-security-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\WEB-INF\classes started by s.movahedi in C:\Windows\system32)
2023-03-27 16:04:50.392  INFO 8400 --- [nio-8085-exec-3] d.d.jpasecurity.ServletInitializer       : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-03-27 16:04:52.694  INFO 8400 --- [nio-8085-exec-3] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-03-27 16:04:52.907  INFO 8400 --- [nio-8085-exec-3] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 186 ms. Found 5 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-03-27 16:04:54.105  INFO 8400 --- [nio-8085-exec-3] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3601 ms
2023-03-27 16:04:55.002  INFO 8400 --- [nio-8085-exec-3] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2023-03-27 16:04:55.202  INFO 8400 --- [nio-8085-exec-3] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.11.Final
2023-03-27 16:04:55.702  INFO 8400 --- [nio-8085-exec-3] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2023-03-27 16:04:56.045  INFO 8400 --- [nio-8085-exec-3] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-03-27 16:04:56.287  INFO 8400 --- [nio-8085-exec-3] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2023-03-27 16:04:56.347  INFO 8400 --- [nio-8085-exec-3] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDBDialect
2023-03-27 16:04:58.504  INFO 8400 --- [nio-8085-exec-3] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2023-03-27 16:04:58.530  INFO 8400 --- [nio-8085-exec-3] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-03-27 16:05:01.292  INFO 8400 --- [nio-8085-exec-3] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure any request with [org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@3e9203ab, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@25224c4d, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@38ca0810, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@4a4d3cf9, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@638cc210, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@1147536c, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@35f5cbc7, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@45dc5b2c, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@8cfce92, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@53f363c7, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@13b0352, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@58796bb8, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@5ad149ae]
2023-03-27 16:05:01.557  WARN 8400 --- [nio-8085-exec-3] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2023-03-27 16:05:02.516  INFO 8400 --- [nio-8085-exec-3] d.d.jpasecurity.ServletInitializer       : Started ServletInitializer in 13.446 seconds (JVM running for 45.114)
2023-03-27 16:05:02.528  INFO 8400 --- [nio-8085-exec-3] d.d.jpasecurity.JpaSecurityApplication   : Root context already created (using as parent).

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.7.4)

2023-03-27 16:05:02.903  INFO 8400 --- [nio-8085-exec-3] d.d.jpasecurity.JpaSecurityApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-03-27 16:05:03.813  INFO 8400 --- [nio-8085-exec-3] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 894 ms
2023-03-27 16:05:03.843  INFO 8400 --- [nio-8085-exec-3] o.s.boot.web.servlet.RegistrationBean    : Filter errorPageFilter was not registered (possibly already registered?)
2023-03-27 16:05:03.843  INFO 8400 --- [nio-8085-exec-3] o.s.boot.web.servlet.RegistrationBean    : Filter springSecurityFilterChain was not registered (possibly already registered?)
2023-03-27 16:05:03.977  INFO 8400 --- [nio-8085-exec-3] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure any request with [org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@178b1a0f, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@6b046b3f, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@74fd8451, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@3ac7391b, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@28005822, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@1cafd4ae, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@2510ad76, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@7a717bc4, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@797d8a70, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@9ecc855, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@669e353, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@67dd3bf9, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@50b598d1]
2023-03-27 16:05:04.072  INFO 8400 --- [nio-8085-exec-3] d.d.jpasecurity.JpaSecurityApplication   : Started JpaSecurityApplication in 1.54 seconds (JVM running for 46.67)
27-Mar-2023 16:05:04.093 INFO [http-nio-8085-exec-3] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-tomcat-8.5.87\webapps\jpa-security-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war] has finished in [24,781] ms
```

Most amazing thing is that the application is get started twice in seprated tomcat context and neety doesnt get started.
Whats the problem?